# Docker-compose: Can I automate compose to run commands inside a container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Okay so I know I can automate my "docker run" instructions like this, say I would do this without compose:

First create the volume

```
docker volume create --name mongodb-shard-1-node-1
```

Then the container

```
docker run --name mongodb-node-1 -d -v mongodb-node-1:/data/db -p 27031:27017 --link mongo-node-2:mongo mongo --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

This would be the same as including this in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
mongodb-node-1:
    image: mongo
    volumes: 
        - "mongodb-node-1:/data/db"
    ports:
        - "27031:27017"
    container_name: mongodb-node-1

    external_links:
        - "mongodb-node-3:mongo"

    command: --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

But I also have to run commands inside the mongodb shell, to do this I first use `exec` to enter the shell like this:

```
docker exec -it mongodb-shard-1-node-1 mongo
```

afterwards inside the shell I need to run commands such as

```
rs.initiate()
```

and others like

```
rs.addArb("172.17.0.6:27017")
```

etc...

**Can I automate these last steps with docker-compose? Is it possible to automate this in docker at all?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly automate it like that, sadly.

As a workaround, you could extend the container to add in a shell script which runs, starts Mongo, then runs the specified commands. You could even pass in that IP address in an environment variable if it needs to be modifiable.

Comment: do you mean "exend the image"? If so, agreed. This is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

[Kontena](http://www.kontena.io) has leveraged docker-compose.yml file format and introduced this kind of functionality by adding `post_start` hook.

`peer:
  image: mongo:3.2
  stateful: true
  command: --replSet kontena --smallfiles
  instances: 3
  hooks:
    post_start:
      - cmd: sleep 10
        name: sleep
        instances: 1
        oneshot: true
      - cmd: mongo --eval "printjson(rs.initiate());"
        name: rs_initiate
        instances: 1
        oneshot: true
      - cmd: mongo --eval "printjson(rs.add('%{project}-peer-2'))"
        name: rs_add2
        instances: 1
        oneshot: true
      - cmd: mongo --eval "printjson(rs.add('%{project}-peer-3'))"
        name: rs_add3
        instances: 1
        oneshot: true`

https://github.com/kontena/examples/blob/master/mongodb-cluster/kontena.yml

`$ kontena app deploy` command will deploy all three mongodb peers and add them to replica set.